# SQL query, date of validity and joins: how to make it work?

Tags: mysql, sql

All the 3 following tables have a "`date_v_end`" field which is a validity date. As long as it's `NULL` this means it's the current "good" value.

For example, to select the current values of the table `categorie` we can simply do `SELECT * FROM categorie WHERE date_v_end IS NULL`.

I have 3 tables:

- a table `categorie` (category in English)
- a table "one to many" `categorie_produit` (category <=> product in English)
- a table `produit` (product in English)

I'd like to make a query of all the *current* `categories`, and their one to many `produit`, and I *still need one result* **even if the category has no product** (= no `produit_categorie` row).

Before having the "`date_v_end`" field I did it this way:

```
SELECT
  c.id AS c_id,
  c.titre AS c_titre,
  c.description AS c_description,
  cp.id_categorie AS cp_id_categorie,
  cp.id_produit AS cp_id_produit,
  p.id AS p_id,
  p.titre AS p_titre,
  p.description AS p_description
FROM categorie_produit cp
LEFT OUTER JOIN categorie c
ON c.id=cp.id_categorie
LEFT OUTER JOIN produit p
ON p.id=cp.id_produit
ORDER BY c_id,p_id;
```

It worked like a charm. Now I'm trying to modify the query with the new "`date_v_end`" field. I've added the three clauses `WHERE c.date_v_fin IS NULL AND cp.date_v_fin IS NULL AND p.date_v_fin IS NULL`. There you go:

```
SELECT
  c.id AS c_id,
  c.titre AS c_titre,
  c.description AS c_description,
  cp.id_categorie AS cp_id_categorie,
  cp.id_produit AS cp_id_produit,
  p.id AS p_id,
  p.titre AS p_titre,
  p.description AS p_description
FROM categorie_produit cp
LEFT OUTER JOIN categorie c
ON (c.id=cp.id_categorie AND c.date_v_fin IS NULL)
LEFT OUTER JOIN produit p
ON (p.id=cp.id_produit AND p.date_v_fin IS NULL)
WHERE cp.date_v_fin IS NULL
ORDER BY c_id,p_id;
```

This works fine except in one circumstance: when there's a `categorie_produit` **and** its "`date_v_end`" is **not** `NULL`: before adding this damn "`date_v_end`" field, I got *one* row with c_id, c_titre, and c_description filled and the other fields `NULL` (`cp_id_categorie`, `cp_id_produit`,`p_id`,`p_titre`,`p_description`). Now there's no result.

I really don't know how I can modify my query to make it work. Any idea?

Comment: Wouldn't you _not_ want that row anyways, as it's not valid?  Or are you not even getting the 'correct' rows?  Besides which, doesn't adding the comparisons to the `WHERE` clause make those `INNER JOIN`s (effectively) - what about moving the `cp.date_v_fin` and `p.date_v_fin` checks into their respective `JOIN` clauses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `IS NULL` check into the JOINs.

In your version you join, regardless of the `date_v_fin` field, and then filter the results.

In the query below a record is only joined if the date_v_fin field IS NULL.

```
SELECT
  c.id AS c_id,
  c.titre AS c_titre,
  c.description AS c_description,
  cp.id_categorie AS cp_id_categorie,
  cp.id_produit AS cp_id_produit,
  p.id AS p_id,
  p.titre AS p_titre,
  p.description AS p_description
FROM
  categorie c
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  categorie_produit cp
    ON  c.id=cp.id_categorie
    AND cp.date_v_fin IS NULL
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  produit p
    ON  p.id=cp.id_produit
    AND p.date_v_fin IS NULL
WHERE
  c.date_v_fin IS NULL
ORDER BY
  c_id,
  p_id
```

Comment: It's incredible. I feel so stupid. I've been working on it for more than 2 hours because I didn't want to ask on stackoverflow (question of proudness). It's almost humiliating to see people like you answering so fast with the right answer **`;)`**

Comment: We all get blinded by the obvious sometimes.  Well, I get blinded by the obvious *most* of the time...

Comment: Which works both ways, I reckon. As much as we can get *blinded* by the obvious, we may also have our chances to demonstrate our astuteness of mind and penetration into the domain in question by *pointing out* the obvious. And then get dubious compliments like @Olivier's. :)